# Pursuing a full-time position while completing coursework for my bachelor's degree

Tags: resume, fulltime

I'm almost done with a computer science major in college, and all but one of my computer science courses will be finished by the end of the next semester. I have 2 years work experience in co-ops and freelancing and several projects which I can use to showcase what I have learned. However, in the spring semester, I have two night classes to go in order to finish my degree -- "life science gen ed" and "theory of computing".

How should I indicate that I will still be a student when applying for full-time positions?

Comment: I already flag the moderator for you to see what they think. Please do not cross post this question yourself. Thanks.

Comment: As suggested by @scaaahu, I'm migrating this to Workplace... it seems on-topic there according to their FAQ.

Comment: Hey Crow, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Your question was a bit open-ended and didn't match the guidelines in our [help/dont-ask], so I made a small [edit]. Hopefully I didn't invalidate your question, but if you think I mucked it up, feel free to make an [edit] of your own. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

1. Make sure to include your major and your expected graduation date in the EDUCATION section.

EDUCATON
Podunk University
B.A. in Comp Sci (expected Fall-2014)

1. I assume that your resume already includes your work experience
2. Then send out your resume immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and this can be indicated in your resume and in your cover letter.

If you are in the United States (and perhaps elsewhere, but United States for sure), additional schooling while doing full-time work can be considered a "conflict of interest" depending on the place of work and, depending on the place of work, it may be grounds for disciplinary action if they find that your schooling is interfering with your job and that you had never told them about it before.

On the one hand, disclosing at the get-go might discourage some potential employers from hiring you (understandably, because what if you lose sleep over exams and projects or homework and can't stay a little later to finish up work, etc).  On the other hand, a potential employer might go, "Oh okay. Just make sure your work is your first priority," and even encourage you in your studies and be supportive or might ask you to join the workforce after you're done with school.

Whatever you do, though, since schooling (or another job) can be considered a "conflict of interest", it is probably best to disclose at the get-go re: resume and/or cover letter.

Comment: I have never heard of a company considering taking additional courses at a college as a conflict of interest. If there is such a company then thats the exact type of company I wouldn't work for.  If they don't want me to invest in myself through formal training then thats something I can't accept.

Comment: Schooling (in the OP's case, two classes required for graduation on top of a full-time job) could potentially affect an employee's ability to put forth 100% into their work (re: as I mentioned in my answer). The fact of the matter is, when it comes to 'jobs', the full-time one is the priority and if there is something else that an employee is pursuing that can negatively impact that first priority work, then it is a potential 'conflict of interest'. My own company is fine with potential 'conflicts of interest' so long as they know about it first and YES, schooling is considered one of them.

Comment: I have actually been taking 4 courses while working full time. I honestly don't get how people can afford to live without working at bare minimum 50 hours per week in an unprofessional job... hence why I am looking for a real job.

Comment: I totally understand and get that (and so do other people including employers and I myself have done work and schooling). It's really a question of "Does this other job/occupation have the potential to affect an employee's current primary job?" If it does, it's a potential conflict of interest (or competition of interest) but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad thing/has negative consequences. You don't -have- to disclose (in some ways, who will know) but if you don't, are you willing to handle the consequences that may come?